# Como fazer um botão que executa 2 eventos?

Tags: javascript

Olá,

Então eu gostaria de saber como eu posso fazer um botão no qual ao clicar pela primeira vez ele altera o conteúdo de um SPAN e na hora que eu clicar novamente ele volta para o valor antigo.

Comment: [Isso](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_lightbulb) é mais ou menos o que você está querendo fazer, porem com 2 botões, mas já da um norte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem várias formas de se fazer isso e, normalmente, não será necessário fazer o botão executar mais de um evento.

Uma forma simples, é sempre manter o próximo valor salvo numa variável.

```js
document.getElementById('bt-toggle').addEventListener('click', fnClick);

var proximoValor = 'Teste 2';
function fnClick() {
  var span = document.getElementById('span');
  
  var aux = span.innerText;
  span.innerText = proximoValor;
  proximoValor = aux;
}
```

```html
<span id="span">Teste 1</span> <br>
<button id="bt-toggle">Toggle</button>
```